# request to reopen questions

Tags: support

Can ask to reopen some of my questions which were closed by unclear reasons:

- 1) https://serverfault.com/questions/168183/open-source-alternatives-to-ms-ad-features-but-installable-on-ms-windows-close

What does it "as subjective and argumentative" mean?

This is typical development problem. If I need shot-term specific feature of AD there is no point to deploy full-fledged MS AD.

I tried to reopen it having found some answers and asking for more 
https://serverfault.com/questions/170286/non-ms-free-alternatives-to-ms-ad-features-installable-on-ms-windows-for-develop
but it was closed as "exact duplicate".

How can opened vs. closed, or having only off-topic + misinformation vs. containing valid info questions be duplicate?

- 2)https://serverfault.com/questions/168763/windows-workgroup-localsystem-vs-domain-ad-localsystem-closed

Why it is not related to "relate to system administration, servers, or professional desktop IT in some way, within the scope defined in the faq"?

- 3) [how to better set up machine for development both in workgroup and Windows domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/169807/how-to-better-set-up-machine-for-development-both-in-workgroup-and-windows-domain)

This is typical problem of development-environment machine setup and configuration/approach

Comment: The biggest problem with both your questions and answer is that they are barely readable.  On questions you answer, you do not appear to understand the question.  On questions you post we do not understand you.  You really need to work improving your English.

Answer (score 2):

When you get 3000 rep, you can vote to reopen yourself. Also, anyone with 3k rep that hasn't already voted to close that question can vote to reopen it as well. There are over 100 users above that reputation threshold, so if it hasn't been reopened, then that means that the general consensus of the community is in line with the 5 that voted to close it in the first place.